# me on with my code on codechef elementary

Tags: c

I face problems with my code when I enter 1 3 4 . although I couldn't find any error as it works perfectly with other numbers / ps. the was built as a solution to the codechef problem [POTATOES](https://www.codechef.com/problems/POTATOES)

> **Problem summary:** Write a program that inputs an integer T followed by T lines containing two space-separated positive integers. For each of these lines, output the smallest number (>1) that, when added to the sum of these two numbers, results in a sum that is a prime number.

and my code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int prime(int a,int b);

int main() {
    int c;
    scanf("%d",&c);
    int a,b,d[c];

    for(a=0; a<c; a++) {
        int x,y;
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        b=(x+y);
        if(prime(x,y)-b!=0)
            d[a]=prime(x,y)-b;
        else d[a]=prime((x+1),y)-b;
    }
    for(a=0; a<c; a++)printf("%d\n",d[a]);

    return 0;
}

int prime(int a,int b) {
    int c,e;
    for(c=2; c<(a+b); c++) {
        if((a+b)%c==0) {
            b++;
            continue;
        }
        return(a+b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your - runnable - code.

Comment: Please include your code. This is necessary. Just copy/paste into the question window, highlight all of it and then press `ctrl`+`k` to format it

Comment: Please also tell us what you have tried, why it didn't work and any errors you get.

Comment: the code has alredy been included in the form of link . I expect people here to read my question properlybefore putting my question on hold ! The problem has also been stated as when I enter  1 3 4 it should return 4 but it returns 3. I had also uploaded the question link .The people who were curious to help went through it and posted valuable comments. It is very pathetic to know that people just put your question on hold even before trying to solve it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong. In your function `prime()` due to the statement `b++;` , `(a+b)` is changing in `(a+b)%c` but the incremented `c` is never went back.So for bigger prime numbers your code **will fail**

Eg:- *(89,1) (79,1) etc*

Also You don't need that `d[c]` in your code. You don't need to store every output.When you compute one output just print it .That is `ok` with code-chef. Also You can divide the problem into to functions.

Try this simplified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int prime(int n);
int make_prime(int a);

int main()
{
    int c;
    scanf("%d", &c);
    int a, b;

    for (a = 0; a < c; a++)
    {
        int x, y;
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        b = (x + y);

        printf("%d\n", make_prime(b));

    }

    return 0;
}

int make_prime(int a) 
{
    int c=1;
    while(prime(a+c)==0){
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}

int prime(int n){ // simple prime function

    int i,flag=1;
    for (i = 2; i <= (n)/2; i++)
    {
        if ((n) % i == 0)
        {
           flag=0;
           break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for making me know where my code was wrong .  Although your code was correct, it took me time to understand what you wanted to do . Meanwhile , I corrected my code and now it works . Thanks for the quick reply (I am a beginer)   . If anyone wants to see my corrected code , : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VRqT9ycCMp/